# problem with Jquery/lavalamp(newbie)

Tags: jquery, html, lavalamp

I have this code:
it will not work I downloaded the includes that needed but no result where I should put the code? I think putting in locations have problem

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-latest.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.lavalamp.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.easing.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() { $(".lavaLamp").lavaLamp({ fx: "backout", speed: 700 })});
</script>
<style>
/* Styles for the entire LavaLamp menu */
.lavaLamp {
    position: relative;
    height: 29px; width: 421px;
    background: url("../image/bg.gif") no-repeat top;
    padding: 15px; margin: 10px 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
    /* Force the list to flow horizontally */
    .lavaLamp li {
        float: left;
        list-style: none;
    }
        /* Represents the background of the highlighted menu-item. */
        .lavaLamp li.back {
            background: url("../image/lava.gif") no-repeat right -30px;
            width: 9px; height: 30px;
            z-index: 8;
            position: absolute;
        }
            .lavaLamp li.back .left {
                background: url("../image/lava.gif") no-repeat top left;
                height: 30px;
                margin-right: 9px;
            }
        /* Styles for each menu-item. */
        .lavaLamp li a {
            position: relative; overflow: hidden;
            text-decoration: none;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            font: bold 14px arial;
            color: #fff; outline: none;
            text-align: center;
            height: 30px; top: 7px;
            z-index: 10; letter-spacing: 0;
            float: left; display: block;
            margin: auto 10px;
        }

</style>

</head>
<body>
<form>        
<ul class="lavaLamp">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Plant a tree</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Travel</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Ride an elephant</a></li>
        </ul>
  <li class="back"><div class="left"></div></li>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you mean that the JS files don't load? Maybe you should link to them from a CDN as explained here: http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery#CDN_Hosted_jQuery

Comment: It will show me nothing in the page I will see just a dot

Comment: I wanted to run the code of this web site:http://www.gmarwaha.com/blog/category/client-side/jquery/#tb

Answer (score 1):

There's an error in your HTML code. You don't need the line

```
<li class="back"><div class="left"></div></li>
```

That line is generated by the lavalamp plugin, so remove it.